# How do I autofill billing info, in a Rails app?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How might I do this? I've looked into it and couldn't find a simple implementation.

Essentially, I have an app that has user subscriptions. In my case the user is associated with an organization and is required to fill in the organization address. There's also the billing information section with a checkbox that says "Check if same name and organization address". When this checkbox is clicked I'd like to port over and autofill all of the address details i.e. state, country etc... from Organization address.

See the billing_information checkbox code below:

```
 <div class="checkbox click">
      <input id="check1" type="checkbox" value="check1" name="check">
      <label for="check1" style="color:#fff !important;" class="checkbox_label"> Check if same name and organization address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <input type="text" class="form-control-input address" placeholder="Address">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <input type="text" class="form-control-input city" placeholder="City">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control-input state" placeholder="State/Province/Region">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control-input zip_code" placeholder="Zip/Postal Code">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6" style="color:#fff; font-size:20px;">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg continue-button">Update</button>
          or <a href="#" class="cancel-t" data-dismiss='modal'>Cancel</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Many e-commerce websites have this feature, and I have the checkbox implemented in my design I'm just having trouble implementing the backend code to make it work. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you need/want the information to appear on the user's screen before the submit button is clicked?  If so, then use Javascript.  Rails can't help you there.

If all you want is for the appropriate data elements to be copied over correctly in the controller, then just do that:

```
order = Order.new(params)
if params[:check1]
  order.shipping_address = order.billing_address
  order.shipping_city = order.billing_city
  order.shipping_zip = order.billing_zip
  order.shipping_state = order.billing_state
  ...
end
...
```